# Mechanical Turk - How to view my own created HITs that I'm not qualified for?

Tags: mechanicalturk

As a requester, after I create HITs I'd like to preview them on the website both on the Sandbox and in Production for various reasons, ranging from final verification to checking up on a particular HIT.

But I have found that I am not able to view my own HITs since the qualifications I've set are beyond what my account when logged in as a worker can view. So I'd like to ask is there a way for a requester to be able to review their HITs even if they themselves do not having matching qualifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options:

1. If they're your own user-defined qualifications, then you can assign them to yourself in the live server and in the sandbox.
2. If they're statistics-type qualifications (like number of HITs completed), you have to actually manually achieve them. You could do this by creating a bunch of HITs for yourself to complete in the sandbox. Tedious, but it's the only way to actually get the qualification.
3. If it's something like masters, there's no way to really make them work in the sandbox unless you follow (2), above, but the definition of master is not public anywhere so it's unclear how much you'd have to do to gain the qualification.
4. You can, of course, remove the qualifications in the sandbox just to test the HIT itself, but that's probably not exactly what you want.

Comment: This is pretty clever: "You could do this by creating a bunch of HITs for yourself to complete in the sandbox."